# curl with Umlaut causes "JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22"

Tags: curl, unicode, special-characters, json, ascii

I'm running below curl command from the command line (Git Bash on Windows) or as part of a Bash Script.

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d "{\"testField\":\"ä\"}" https://someurl...
```

The body of the curl command has an **Umlaut ä**.

The server which is a Spring Boot REST API running in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Container returns the following error:

```
JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 17]
```

The same curl command imported into Postman works just fine, so I believe it's rather a curl issue than a server problem.

Comment: Why not use a Unicode escape?

Comment: The inputs come from users either as a copy paste or a text file, so I'd like to avoid having to manually convert any extended ascii characters.

Comment: The issue isn't really the accented character; it's that the data encoding does not match the parse encoding. How would your system react if the input were, say, ISO 2022-JP encoded instead of (I assume) Windows code page 1252? Just ignoring text within quotes doesn't cut it, because 0x22 is not always *"* in ISO 2022-JP. Can you enforce a specific input encoding? If not, can you reliably determine the encoding given?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the character `ä` with its UTF8 encoding `\u00e4`:

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"testField":"u00e4"}' https://someurl..
```

Comment: The inputs come from users either as a copy paste or via a text file, so I'd like to avoid having to manually convert any extended ascii characters.

Comment: Then you'll need to use a Unicode encoding library of some kind.  There are ones available in most popular languages (Python, PHP), so just choose your favorite...

Comment: If you want to stick to bash, you can probably use jq.  For instance: `echo '{"testField":"u00e4"}' | jq . -a` yields `{ "testField": "u00e4" }`.